# Python fetching a single tuple reversed from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am unsure about the question, but it has me troubled for a brief time now.

I have a dictionary for the pixel dimensions of various paper sizes against 4 seperate PPI's as follows

```py
paperSizes = {
    "A0": {
        "72": {2384, 3370},
        "96": {3179, 4494},
        "150": {4967, 7022},
        "300": {9933, 14043}
    },
    "A1": {
        "72": {1684, 2384},
        "96": {2245, 3179},
        "150": {3508, 4967},
        "300": {7016, 9933}
    },
    "A2": {
        "72": {1191, 1684},
        "96": {1587, 2245},
        "150": {2480, 3508},
        "300": {4960, 7016}
    },
    "A3": {
        "72": {842, 1191},
        "96": {1123, 1587},
        "150": {1754, 2480},
        "300": {3508, 4960}
    },
    "A4": {
        "72": {595, 842},
        "96": {794, 1123},
        "150": {1240, 1754},
        "300": {2480, 3508}
    }
}
```

Now, Only when I try to fetch A4 at 72 ppi, i get the dimension in reversed order.

```sh
>>> print(paperSizes["A4"]["72"])
{842, 595}
>>> print(paperSizes["A4"]["96"])
{794, 1123}
```

This has been causing issues for me and I simply cant understand why this is happening
Is there an underlying dictionary behavior I am unaware of?

Comment: My Apologies, I referred to them as tuple because that was the first word stuck at the back of my brain since I was expanding them with * as an argument call. And I agree, it is a set, I just now noticed. that I wrote tuple instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than taking a set use lists and it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`set` objects will not guarantee the order, you could use lists, to convert your sets to lists you can use:

```
paperSizes = {k: {i: sorted(j) for i, j in d.items()} for k, d in paperSizes.items()}
```

now you can print and get the exptected result:

```
print(paperSizes["A4"]["72"])

# [595, 842]
```